# How can i bulk delete using knexjs(MySQL). I have entries in an array which matches a single field

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

let i have database structure like this.

```
sr no.       name         age
 1.         hemant          25
 2.          amit           23
 3.         vikash          24
```

and i have array like following:

```
arr=['hemant','amit'];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `whereIn` statement:

```
var arr = ['hemant', 'amit'];

knex('table')
  .whereIn('name', arr)
  .del();
```

Comment: Show this SQL query.